# A vector of vector problems

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector

I'm trying to loop through a list of strings and find where a given character is located at in said string. I then store the string in a given vector based on where/if the character occurs. I'm getting a runtime error in the following code before the loop finishes executing. I've looked over the it half a dozen times already and can't seem to find anything wrong.

```
vector< vector<string> > p;
for(list< string >::iterator ix = dictionary.begin(); ix != dictionary.end(); ix++)
{
    int index = contains(*ix, guess);
    index++;

    p.at(index).push_back(*ix); //0 will contain all the words that do not contain the letter
                                //1 will be the words that start with the char
                                //2 will be the words that contain the the char as the second letter
                                //etc...
}



int contains(string str, char c)
{
    char *a = (char *)str.c_str();
    for(int i = 0; i < (str.size() + 1); i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == c)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vector< vector > p defines p as empty vector. You must have vector elements added to it before using vector::at().
For example:

```
const size_t MAX_LETTERS_IN_WORD = 30;
vector< vector<string> > p(MAX_LETTERS_IN_WORD);

/* same as before */
```

As an alternative you can check p.size() before using at() and push_back() additional elements into p as needed

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 (str.size() + 1)
```

...to

```
 str.size()
```

You would be in undefined territory at str.size(), let alone that PLUS one.

For that matter, why are you fiddling with the extra char* instead of std::string[]?

For *THAT* matter, why don't you simply use [std::string::find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)?

That is, of course, assuming you're using std::string and not some other string... :)

In fact, back to the call site... string::find() returns the index of where the target character matched, or string::npos if NOT matched. So, can you dispense with the extra function altogether?

```
 int pos = (*ix).find( guess );
 p.at( (  pos == string::npos ) ? 0 : ( pos + 1 ) ).push_back( *ix );
```

Comment: And, as indicated by the other folks here, you really should populate p before you try to poke around at it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the runtime error, might be because you access the vector `p` at a position that doesn't exist yet. You have to make space in the vector before you access a specific index.